# Where can I find a map of songthaew lines in Yangon?

Tags: public-transport, maps, myanmar, yangon

There exist some detailed maps for buses in Yangon ([example](https://www.myanmore.com/2017/08/ultimate-yangon-bus-ride/)  ([mirror](http://archive.is/jy8iZ))). Where can I find similar maps for [songthaews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Songthaew) in Yangon? I saw many songthaews in Yangon ([video example](https://youtu.be/gCdgRT2f63k?t=21) taken near [Danyingon railway station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danyingon_railway_station)), so they seem to be a common means of transportation used by locals in that area.

Comment: Are you sure they have set routes, or do they act more like taxis?  (I have no idea, just asking)

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica same here, no idea! Given the number of passengers I have seen on some of them (> 15), that'd be some serious carpooling if they operate like taxis.

Comment: yeah, while I didn't use them, there were some buses in Bolivia that seemed to basically pick up people going roughly to suburb x, where they'd be dropped off.  So sorta pooling for a direction.  And in uzbekistan you'd hire a seat in a taxi between cities, and then get dropped off at your hotel/destination once there (sometimes. /shakes fist at Khujand drivers ).

Comment: If it's the same as in say Bombay, there are indeed NO such formal lines, it's just an informal thing.  All the drivers know that at about Xpm about X many folks want to go to X location.  But then, I don't even know where or what a "Yangon" is  :-O

Comment: FWIW, "songthaew" is Thai and not a word that will be used or understood in Yangon.  The local term appears to be "bus kaa", but don't quote me on that...

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I am not an expert in Myanmar or Yangon, and am writing this answer under the assumption that Songthaews are a form of informal transit operated independently by local people. [Additional note: The word seems to be Thai when googled, not Burmese. The local term may be different.]

There is almost certainly no unified map of the system, and the locals using them most likely know the routes by word of mouth. It is likely that many follow the same route driven exclusively by passenger demand, but the actual routes have no individual identification. To use the system effectively, you will need to speak the language or travel with someone who is native to Yangon, as they will know which routes will take them to specific destinations.

Takeaway: If you're looking for public transportation maps in Yangon, I'd stick with the existing bus maps and bus network since it is likely that no map of informal transportation exists. Buses will most likely be the easier way to get around the city.

General reading on mapping informal transit: https://www.citylab.com/transportation/2014/02/what-informal-transit-looks-when-you-actually-map-it/8283/